# What is getOpcode in LLVM?

Tags: assembly, llvm, code-generation, opcode

What does the function `getOpcode()` return in the `MCInstrDesc` or `MachineInstr` class in the LLVM code generator part? I am not able to relate to the actual opcode of the machines.

For example, the `getOpcode()` function returns `2515` for `RET` instruction in `x86`. However, the real opcode in x86 is `C3` (`195` in decimal).

What is the relation?

Comment: http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Instruction.html#ab4e05d690df389b8b1477c90387b575f

Comment: Well, my problem is that it does not match with Intel's opcode as I explained in my example.
Also, I am working with `MachineInstr` and not `Instruction` of IR.

Comment: The documentation says everything you need to know.  The opcode is part of an enumeration, it is not the opcode used in the binary.

Comment: It's internal value, some kind of enum, not sure how/where it is defined,  I got spoiled by IDEs where I can click on the item and go after definition, and I don't have LLVM sources installed. It's not related to target platform machine code instructions. You can check the next API function `getOpcodeName` (check the C implementation for example how the "opcode" value is used) to get something like `"add"` string for `Instruction::Add` value.

Answer (score 4):

The `getOpcode()` member function on `MCInstrDesc` and `MachineInstr` returns the enum value that identifies which opcode in [`X86InstrInfo.td`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/1cb64026709ddf4b7cbb090faef8457968df581a/lib/Target/X86/X86InstrInfo.td) the instruction represents. Within other backends the numbering corresponds to that backend's instr info, typically a file called `[BACKEND]InstrInfo.td`.

You can find an example of this being used in many of the X86 backend passes, for example the following code in [`X86ExpandPseudo.cpp`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/1cb64026709ddf4b7cbb090faef8457968df581a/lib/Target/X86/X86ExpandPseudo.cpp#L76) that deals with tail call returns.

```
switch (MI.getOpcode()) {
default:
  return false;
case X86::TCRETURNdi:
case X86::TCRETURNdicc:
case X86::TCRETURNri:
case X86::TCRETURNmi:
case X86::TCRETURNdi64:
case X86::TCRETURNdi64cc:
case X86::TCRETURNri64:
case X86::TCRETURNmi64: {
  /* ... */
}
/* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling about same question recently and finally got it. It's been a long time since your question, but I'm writing this for if someone has still confusion.

As you said [getOpcode()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1MCInst.html#a5c26b1db954c27889986dba3b310a8e4) function returns enum of machine instructions and these **are not** holding at `{BackendArchName}InstrInfo.td` as @dtolnay said. These enums will be **generated after LLVM library built** and it is not related to real decimal opcode numbers, and also opcode's decimal enum representations can be changing thanks to different llvm versions or custom changes in library about the backend. That sounds reasonable because it does not prevent customization, you can add or remove opcodes in a backend and after library built, enums of opcodes dynamically being changed and generated. If these enums were persistent in somewhere in the library before built, e.g probably you couldn't add new opcodes for a target or
it would probably be hard to change small details like that.

So, after built you can find files with these opcode representations at this folder:

`{your-llvm-directory}/{your-llvm-build-directory}/lib/Target/{which-backend-target}`

and this `.inc` file includes enums for opcodes:

`{which-backend-target}GenInstrInfo.inc`

For example after built for riscv target in my pc I can find enums here:

`~/llvm/llvm-project/build/lib/Target/RISCV/RISCVGenInstrInfo.inc`

A part of these enums:

```cpp
/*===- TableGen'erated file -------------------------------------*- C++ -*-===*\
|*                                                                            *|
|* Target Instruction Enum Values and Descriptors                             *|
|*                                                                            *|
|* Automatically generated file, do not edit!                                 *|
|*                                                                            *|
\*===----------------------------------------------------------------------===*/

#ifdef GET_INSTRINFO_ENUM
#undef GET_INSTRINFO_ENUM
namespace llvm {

namespace RISCV {
  enum {

// ........................................

    AND = 323,
    ANDI    = 324,
    ANDN    = 325,
    AUIPC   = 326,
    BDEP    = 327,
    BDEPW   = 328,
    BEQ = 329,
    BEXT    = 330,
    BEXTW   = 331,
    BFP = 332,
    BFPW    = 333,
    BGE = 334,
    BGEU    = 335,
    BLT = 336,
    BLTU    = 337,
    BMATFLIP    = 338,
    BMATOR  = 339,
    BMATXOR = 340,
    BNE = 341,
    CLMUL   = 342,
    CLMULH  = 343,
    CLMULHW = 344,
    CLMULR  = 345,
    CLMULRW = 346,
    CLMULW  = 347,
    CLZ = 348,
    CLZW    = 349,
    CMIX    = 350,
    CMOV    = 351,
    CRC32B  = 352,

// ........................................

    CRC32H  = 358,
    CRC32W  = 359,
    CSRRC   = 360,
    CSRRCI  = 361,
    CSRRS   = 362,
    CSRRSI  = 363,
    CSRRW   = 364,
    CSRRWI  = 365,
    CTZ = 366,
    CTZW    = 367,
    C_ADD   = 368,
    C_ADDI  = 369,
    C_ADDI16SP  = 370,
    C_ADDI4SPN  = 371,
    C_ADDIW = 372,
    C_ADDI_HINT_IMM_ZERO    = 373,
    C_ADDI_HINT_X0  = 374,
    C_ADDI_NOP  = 375,
// ........................................

  };

} // end namespace RISCV
} // end namespace llvm
```

I just gave an example for RISCV it is same process for other targets like X86. In your example `2515` for `RET` should be in `X86GenInstrInfo.inc` file as enum number like above.

Because these enums generated after built, it is normal to not find these in any unbuilt [llvm library](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/) like in github.

EXTRA INFORMATION:

Because enum numbers can change for different scenarios you should not use them as number when you are using LLVM C++ API, you should call them with enum names. For example:

```cpp
#include "RISCV.h" //You should include backend header for using enums.
#include "llvm/MC/MCInst.h"

//Some code here ... 

if(MI->getOpcode() == RISCV::ADD){  // MI is machine instruction for example const MCInst *MI

//Some code here...

}

//Some code here...
```

Above code, as you can see no matter what number returns getOpcode function because I can control it with name which derived from (RISCV header->RISCV namespace->RISCV Opcode Enum Name). However, if you want to get directly the name of returned enum number you can use [getOpcodeName](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1MCInstPrinter.html#a62c484cd2ea7bf71dad8fd6d223864bb) function for example:

```cpp
#include "llvm/MC/MCInst.h"
#include "llvm/MC/MCInstPrinter.h"
#include "llvm/ADT/StringRef.h" //for llvm string variable

//Some code here ... 

StringRef opcodeName = IP.getOpcodeName(MI->getOpcode()); // IP is instruction printer for example MCInstPrinter &IP

//Some code here ...
```